# Error: Audio playback was aborted IE 11 Windows 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-audio

I have folder structure like

**Folder interactive_pages_test**

`C:\Users\username\Desktop\interactive_pages_test\test.html`

`C:\Users\username\Desktop\interactive_pages_test\2_Hot_Cross_Buns.mp3`

**Folder test**

`C:\Users\username\Desktop\test\test.html`

`C:\Users\username\Desktop\test\2_Hot_Cross_Buns.mp3`

The files `test.html` and `2_Hot_Cross_Buns.mp3` are same. When I opened `C:\Users\username\Desktop\interactive_pages_test\test.html` in IE 11 it is throwing an`Error: Audio playback was aborted`. But `C:\Users\username\Desktop\test\test.html` is playing fine in IE. In chrome and Mozilla both of the files are playing fine. Can any one please advice on this issue?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tile</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            alert("hi");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio src="./2_Hot_Cross_Buns.mp3"  controls="">Audio not supported</audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually IE's in Windows 8 are above uses activeX control for playing audios, so when you the html file it prompts that ActiveX control is blocked, if you click on allow blocked content then it will play normally.

[Prompt for activex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB2xk.png)

[After Enabling blocked content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuN4q.png)

Comment: But my IE is not prompting :(. I had tested this in another computer then IE